# Matrix as a sum of two commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The problem I'm attempting is to prove that, given an n x n matrix $A$, we can find matrices $B$ & $C$ such that $BC=CB$, $A=B+C$, $B$ is diagonalizable, and $C^n = 0$. I first tried simply breaking the matrix into upper & lower triangular matrices, but one is not guaranteed to be diagonalizable and the two don't necessarily commute. I'm considering having $B$ simply be $\lambda I$, but guaranteeing that $C^n=0$ seems tricky. Any suggestions?

Comment: This stuff is really equivalent to find a matrix's Jordan form (or Weyr form).  Have you learned about Jordan form yet?

Comment: Yes! We learned about it recently. A bit unsure about how it helps, though- the Jordan Form is not necessarily diagonalizable or nilpotent, right?

Comment: It looks like my question has already been answered elsewhere, never mind.

Comment: @SarahH note that they don't mention in the question that $D$ and $N$ commute.  They do commute because of how the "blocks" end up matching up, as you should verify.

Comment: @SarahH also, it is worth noting that this is the [Jordan-Chevalley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition) decomposition of a matrix.